# Fetch HBase Column in Bash Array Using Impala

Tags: bash, hadoop, hbase, impala

I have following data in HBase Table named HISTORY.

```
ID    VALUES
51    101
52    102
```

---

```
QUERY="SELECT VALUES FROM HISTORY";
```

How to apply the above query on HBase table to fetch data in bash array using Impala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Code Works:

```
HOST="localhost";
QUERY="SELECT VALUES FROM HISTORY";
VALUES=($(TERM=ansi impala-shell --impalad $HOST --delimited --quiet --query $QUERY));
```